# Verifying email and password input from a mysql database via php

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying my best at the review and pursue section for chapter 15 of Larry Ullman's PHP and MySQL book 4th edition, **login_ajax.php**, where it said:

> Modify login_ajax.php so that it uses a database to confirm successful login.

This is what I've tried so far, whatever I do, the response I get seems to always be "INCORRECT" and then the ajax script never logs me in.

My code so far:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['email'], $_GET['password'])){

$email = $_GET['email'];
$password = $_GET['password'];

// Need a valid email address:
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

    // must match specific values:
    // This values will be gotten from a database

    require('../mysqli_connect.php');

    // retrieve from database

    $q = "SELECT email, pass FROM users WHERE email = '$email'LIMIT 1";

    // run the query
    $r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);


    //$check_email = "";
    //$check_pass = "";

    /*while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

        $check_email = $row['email'];
        $check_pass = $row['pass'];

    }*/   // if the email and password match those in database

    //if (($email == $check_email && $password == $check_pass)) {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0) {

        echo 'CORRECT';


    } else {

        echo 'INCORRECT';
    }



    mysqli_close($dbc);


    /*    if(($_GET['email'] == 'email@example.com') && ($_GET['password'] == 'testpass')){

            //Set a cookie, if you want, or start a session.
            // indicate  success:
            echo 'CORRECT';

        }else{// mismatch

            echo'INCORRECT';
        }*/
}else{ // invalid email

    echo 'INVALID_EMAIL';
}

}else{ // missing one of the two variables

echo 'INCOMPLETE';

}
```

It contains my different tries.

Comment: Need space before limit `'$email' LIMIT 1";` Better use prepare statement. Remove  `@` before `mysqli_query`

Comment: remove `@` sign from `@mysqli_query` so that you can see when your query has errors

Comment: An aside, use the [password API](http://php.net/password) and stop using plain test passwords.

Comment: try using checking isset method for both in diff case. if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) Not sure though.

Comment: thanks gonna try your suggestions @Saty and give feedbacks

Comment: wow it works, I added the space before LIMIT and removed the '@' and voila!! it worked, the response is supposed to be used by an ajax script to confirm the login.... thanks guys...u boosted my confidence

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I would never use GET to commit a password for security reason.
To check, if a password is correct, I would suggest to use the php function [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.password-verify.php) to store the passwords not in plain text.

But to answer your origin question: To see the errors of your query, simply remove the "@" sign in front of your query. I would also add a space before the "LIMIT" statement.

If it still doesn't work correctly, try to get the mysqli error and post it.

Good luck :)

Comment: just hearing about those functions for the firsty, password_hash()and password_verify(), will sure look up on them, thanks for your suggestions @MarvinX

Comment: thanks  a million, it finally worked with your suggestions, i'm quite new to all these but gonna give password security and try @MarvinX

Answer (score 1):

you only check `email` but you also check your `password` field

if `email` is correct so `user` will login with `wrong password`

try this query

```
$q = "SELECT email, pass FROM users WHERE email = '$email' and password = '$password' LIMIT 1";
```

and `space` between `$email` and `LIMIT`

**or**

remove `@` from `mysqli_query` so its give `error` for better understaning

Comment: thanks for the headsup about the password check, gonna add that, the script finally worked with the suggestions to limit and @

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show the HTML, but I will try to answer with what you gave me.

1. Add a space between `'$email'` and `LIMIT`
2. Make sure you have data in the database.
3. Double check the HTML where you set the `name` attribute in the form and be sure it matches the `$_GET[]` name.